# primeNG p-checkbox Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, primeng

I get the error message "Cannot find control with unspecified name attribute" when using a primeng  as indicated on their website. 
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/checkbox

My code is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Validators, FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'primary-contact',
    templateUrl: './primary-contact.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./primary-contact.component.scss']
})

export class PrimaryContactComponent {

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

primaryContactForm: FormGroup;

ngOnInit() {

    this.primaryContactForm = this.fb.group({
        'preferredCall': new FormControl(),
        'preferredText': new FormControl(),
        'preferredEmail': new FormControl()
    })
  }
}
```

Template is:

```
<span class="form-element">
    Notification Preferences
        <div class="group">
            <label>
                <p-checkbox label="Call" [formControl]="primaryContactForm.get['preferredCall']"></p-checkbox>
            </label>
            <label>
                <p-checkbox label="Text" [formControl]="primaryContactForm.get['preferredText']"></p-checkbox>
            </label>
            <label>
                <p-checkbox label="Email" [formControl]="primaryContactForm.get['preferredEmail']"></p-checkbox>
            </label>
        </div>
</span>
```

I have tried adding the name attribute to the three p-checkboxes, both unique and similar value but it did not fix the problem.

Using the attribute formControlName instead of [formControl] clears the error but according to the primefaces website this is not recommended on the p-checkbox.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like the primeng documentation is not accurate `primaryContactForm.get['preferredCall']` returns undefined so the error you are getting is correct, there is no form control found with that name. Instead you should be using `primaryContactForm.controls['preferredCall']`

Someone pointed this out to them in October and they still haven't updated their documentation, so you may want to fix their documentation and submit a pull request.
https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/2906#issuecomment-334457107

Here is a demo showing the form working when you switch from .get to .controls
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1gs8ju?file=app%2Fapp.component.html